# Linking Images to different views in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

After 2 days of searching and trying all sorts of code snippets and explanations, i need to ask for some help here!

**Demo:**
http://kachipun.se/sandbox/touch/

**Problem:**
On the landing page of the app i have 8 instances of the same image (Planning to dress them up as buttons later on). I want to link these individual images to the 8 different views i have listed up in a menu up to the left.

As i've understood it, i need to use setActiveItem(), but however i try i cant get it to work ;/

**Resources:**
For this particular project i've used wozznik's Slider Menu as a base for the menu, and im building on that.

It contains a store with the data of the different views.

```
Ext.define('SliderMenu.store.MenuOptions', {    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [,
    ],

    config: {
        model: 'SliderMenu.model.MenuOption',
        storeId: 'MenuOptionsStore',

        //Customize your menu options
        data: [
            {id: 1, view: 'SliderMenuDemo.view.Start', iconCls: 'basic', iconMask:true, text:'Start'},
            {id: 2, view: 'SliderMenuDemo.view.MC', iconCls: 'basic', iconMask:true, text:'Machining Center'},
            {id: 3, view: 'SliderMenuDemo.view.TC', iconCls: 'basic', iconMask:true, text:'Turning Center'},
            {id: 4, view: 'SliderMenuDemo.view.ST', iconCls: 'basic', iconMask:true, text:'Silent Tools'},
            {id: 5, view: 'SliderMenuDemo.view.HC', iconCls: 'basic', iconMask:true, text:'Heavy Cuts'},
            {id: 6, view: 'SliderMenuDemo.view.MT', iconCls: 'basic', iconMask:true, text:'Multi Task'},
            {id: 7, view: 'SliderMenuDemo.view.SH', iconCls: 'basic', iconMask:true, text:'Sliding Head'},
            {id: 8, view: 'SliderMenuDemo.view.VTL', iconCls: 'basic', iconMask:true, text:'VTL'},
            {id: 9, view: 'SliderMenuDemo.view.Web', iconCls: 'basic', iconMask:true, text:'Web'},
        ]
    }
});
```

And on the landing view (Start.js) i have the images setup like this with listeners listening for taps on the different images (check console log):

```
items: [{            
                   html: '<div class="gridwrapper">'+
                  '<img class="test1 normal" src="http://static.flickr.com/43/102997171_f9263d8797_o.jpg" width="23%" />'+
                  '<img class="test2 normal" src="http://static.flickr.com/43/102997171_f9263d8797_o.jpg" width="23%" />'+
                  '<img class="test3 normal" src="http://static.flickr.com/43/102997171_f9263d8797_o.jpg" width="23%" />'+
                  '<img class="test4 normal" src="http://static.flickr.com/43/102997171_f9263d8797_o.jpg" width="23%" />'+
                  '<img class="test5 normal" src="http://static.flickr.com/43/102997171_f9263d8797_o.jpg" width="23%" />'+
                  '<img class="test6 normal" src="http://static.flickr.com/43/102997171_f9263d8797_o.jpg" width="23%" />'+
                  '<img class="test7 normal" src="http://static.flickr.com/43/102997171_f9263d8797_o.jpg" width="23%" />'+
                  '<img class="test8 normal" src="http://static.flickr.com/43/102997171_f9263d8797_o.jpg" width="23%" />'+
                  '</div>',

                },
                {
              }],


        listeners: [{        
            element: 'element',          
            delegate: 'img.test1',          
            event: 'tap',          
            fn: function() {
                console.log('One!');
              }      
        },{            
            element: 'element',          
            delegate: 'img.test2',          
            event: 'tap',          
            fn: function() {
               console.log('Two!');
              }
        }
```

I really hope that you guys can help me make sense of this!

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try:
listeners: [{        
            element: 'element',          
            delegate: 'img.test1',          
            event: 'tap',          
            fn: function() {
                Ext.getCmp("maincard").changeViewTo(Ext.create("SliderMenuDemo.view.SH"));
                // alternative: Ext.getCmp("SliderMenu.view.Main").changeViewTo(Ext.create("SliderMenuDemo.view.SH"));
              }      
        }
```

Comment: Hmmm.. Im getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null' From this?